# ReatctJS - Plain vanilla event listeners binding order

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm new to React and trying to implement a few plain vanilla JS listeners outside of any components.  The click events don't change the page content in any way, only the visibility of the dropdown menu, so I didn't think it made sense to have them inside a component.

When I click the `profileIcon` div, the dropdown becomes visible as expected.  However, when I click anywhere on the body, the dropdown is then hidden.  This happens even though I'm trying to stop propagation in the `dropdown` listener.

When I added console statements, I noticed that the body listener is getting called before the dropdown listener, essentially no matter what I do (e.g., order of addition, calling various timeout functions, changing the body listener to `document.getElementById("root")` etc.).

```
document.getElementById("profileIcon").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    document.getElementById("dropdown").style.visibility = "visible"        
})

document.getElementById("dropdown").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log("dropdown")
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
})

document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("body")
    document.getElementById("dropdown").style.visibility = "hidden"
}, true)
```

The event listeners are all being added inside `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")` as it fails otherwise.

I really have no idea what to do here.  Any ideas?

**SOLUTION:**

I removed `true` from the body listener, and changed the `profileIcon` listener to this:

```
document.getElementById("profileIcon").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    dropdown.style.visibility = "visible"
}, true)
```

Comment: So, what does this have to do with React?

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that the body listener is getting called before the dropdown listener

Because you are telling it to. If `true` is passed as third argument to `addEventListener`, the handler is executing in the capturing phase of the event, not the bubbling phase.

See [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616694/218196)

> I really have no idea what to do here. Any ideas?

Don't pass `true`.

Comment: Okay, I had taken out true and then it wasn't working at all.  I realize now that it's because the listener on `profileIcon` was essentially getting immediately canceled because `body` was getting called first.  I'll update the question with the modification to the `profileIcon` listener.

Comment: Correction to the above - the `body` listener was getting called immediately after the `profileIcon` listener and canceling it.

Comment: You should never (*almost*) manipulate the DOM directly when working with React. If you need to change the state of your components, do that within the components.